# Screen partition in Tailwind CSS

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I am trying to create two divisions side by side such the one division should be 1/3 of the remaining screen and other should be 2/3. I am new to Tailwind and while going through the documentation, it says to use

```
<div class="flex ...">
  <div class="w-1/3 ...">w-1/3</div>
  <div class="w-2/3 ...">w-2/3</div>
</div>
```

When I am trying to do so, I am not getting the desired output.

My code:

```
import React from 'react'

const Dashboard = () => {
  return (
    
    <div class="flex">
  <div class="w-1/3 bg-blue-400">
   This should be the 1/3 of the remaining screen (ie screen excluding sidebar )
  </div>
  <div class="w-2/3 bg-blue-800">
    This div should be 2/3 of the remaining screen (ie screen excluding sidebar)
  </div>
</div>
    
  )
}

export default Dashboard
```

[image]

I am not getting where I am doing wrong, Please help

Sidebar code:

```
import React from 'react'

const Sidebar = () => {
  return (
    <>
    <div className="flex flex-col h-screen w-64 bg-sidenavbar">
  
  <div className="flex items-center justify-center h-16 p-bottom-10">
    <span className="text-white text-2xl font-bold">My App</span>
  </div>

  
  <div className="flex flex-col flex-1 overflow-y-auto">
    <button className="px-6 py-3 text-white text-left hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-texthover">
      Dashboard
    </button>
    <button  className="px-6 py-3 text-white text-left hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-texthover">
      Messages
    </button>
    <button  className="px-6 py-3 text-white text-left hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-texthover">
      Calander
    </button>
    <button  className="px-6 py-3 text-white text-left hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-texthover">
      Campaigns
    </button>
  </div>

 
  <div className="flex items-center justify-center h-16">
    <span className="text-gray-300">© 2023 My App. All rights reserved.</span>
  </div>
</div>
    </>
  )
}

export default Sidebar
```

App.js

```
import  Dashboard from "./components/Dashboard";
import Sidebar from "./components/Sidebar";
import Messages from "./components/Messages";

import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  RouterProvider,
  Navigate
} from "react-router-dom";

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    element:<Dashboard/>,
  },
  {
    path: '/messages',
    element: <Messages/>,
  }
];

const routeConfig = createBrowserRouter(routes);

function App() {
  return (
    <>
  <div className='flex'>
    <Sidebar/>
  <RouterProvider router={routeConfig}/>
  </div>
  </>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: the screenshot shows it does work, where is the left black sidebar? i dont see it in the code. consider providing a live example

Comment: The left sidebar is another component. That would be static for all pages. For Dashboard page, I want two div in the remaining screen (full screen excluding the sidebar), such that one of the div sould be 1/3 of remaing screen and other should be 2/3

Comment: it looks correct in the picture

Comment: I could see the remaing white screen in the right, so it has not taken the 1/3 of remaining screen

Comment: oh i did not notice that :) can you re-create it on Codesandbox and similar sites?

Comment: Is the sidebar component, included in the normal flow of the document? That would likely explain why your sizes are off.

Comment: I have added the sidebar code above in the edit.

Comment: Does the flex container containing the w-1/3 and w-2/3 take up the full screen? It looks like the proportions are correct, but it's just not filling up the space correctly.

Comment: @eten, no it is not taking up the full screen, there is a white space left in the right.

Comment: Can you add the main app code where sidebar and dashboard are put together?

Comment: Added the app.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem is, that, while the two containers on the right side have a correct defined width or ratio using w-1/3 and w-2/3, their parent container has no instructions to fill up the whole remaining space on the site. This results in the parent container only being as wide as it´s content or as some default values are telling it to be. The correct way to tell a flexbox container to fill up the remaining space is by using the `flex-1` class in Tailwind CSS. This class sets the `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink`, and `flex-basis` properties, which tells the container to fill up all the available space.

Here's the corrected code for your Dashboard component:

```
import React from 'react'

const Dashboard = () => {
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-1">
      <div className="w-1/3 bg-blue-400">
        This should be 1/3 of the remaining screen (i.e., screen excluding the sidebar)
      </div>
      <div className="w-2/3 bg-blue-800">
        This div should be 2/3 of the remaining screen (i.e., screen excluding the sidebar)
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Dashboard
```

However, what you got here is not a Tailwind issue, it´s more of a flexbox knowledge thing I would say. So of course, feel free to read more about this topic.